# Floating Point Exception with File Redirection in C

Tags: c

I am working on a program that takes a list of numbers from an input file and then takes the factorial of each number and finds the amount of each prime factor within the factorial. for example: if the input file just had one line that had "4" on it the program would take that file (input.txt) and then output the amount that each prime factor occurs which in this case is three 2's and one 3, (4! = 4*3*2*1 = 2*3*2*2 = (2^3)*(3^1) which would output the following:

```
4! = (2^3)*(3^1)
```

Every-time I compile the program it works fine but when i go to input the file ( ./a.out < input.txt) it returns "Floating point exception" and I have gone through the code and placed various printf statements to try and find which section of the code this error is occurring but it always returns the same thing and I was wondering if anyone can help me out. The code and input.txt are down below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Storage_array[5]; // array creating to store the values of the input text file (input.txt)

int current_prime, next_prime, prime_count, prime_number; // variables that involve the calculation and count of prime numbers
int factorial, factorial_current, factorial_next_num; //variables that invlove the handling of the input factorials
int num, current_number, total_number; //variables at help test if a number is prime of not

int find_prime_count(int factorial, int prime_number); //3 functions declared below main()
int find_next_prime(int factorial, int current_prime);
int is_prime(int num);

int a, b, c; //utility varbles

main() 
{
    if((a=scanf("%d", &c)) == EOF) //checks to see if file is empty
    {       
        return 0;
    }
    for(b=0; b<c; b++) 
    {
        if((a=scanf("%d", &c)) == EOF) //checks to see if reached end of the file
        {
            break;
        }
        scanf("%d", &Storage_array[b]); //paces values from file into the storage array
        printf("%d! = ", Storage_array[b]); //formatting the output
        for(c=0;c<5;c++)
        {
            if(c=0) //creating a base case
            {
                current_prime = 2;
            }
            else
            {           
                current_prime = next_prime; //updates the current prime after the base case
                next_prime = find_next_prime(Storage_array[b], current_prime); //performes the outside functions that fine the next                                                     prime number within the factorial
                prime_count = find_prime_count(Storage_array[b], current_prime); //performs outside function that finds the number                                                  of the current prime within the factorial
                printf("(%d^%d)",current_prime ,next_prime); //prints the results in proper format
            }

        }
        printf("\n"); //spaces between factorial numbers
    }
}

/* This function takes an integer as input and then determines if it is a prime number by finding the remainder when the input number is divided by all numbers leading up to the input number exept the number itself and 1, if it is a prime number it returns the prime number, if not it returns 0 */

int is_prime(int num) //function that determines if the input number is a prime number or not
{
    for(a=2; a<num; a++) //base case knowing lowest prime is 2
    {
        if (num % a == 0) //determines if the number is a prime number using remainder when divided by various numbers
        {
            return a; //returns the number if it is prime
        }
    }
}

/* This function takes 2 integers as input (a factorial number and a prime number) and then counts the amount of times that prime number can fit into the factorial, if it can divide with a 0 remainder it divides the factorial by that amount and then stores the amount of times before going to next number within the factorial, after it has divided the entire factorial it returns the number of times the prime number fit */

int find_prime_count (int factorial, int prime_number)
{
    for(a=0;a<factorial;a++)//tests all possible prime numbers under the input factorial
    {
        if(a=0) //base case for lowest possible prime in factorial
        {       
            factorial_current = 1;
            factorial_next_num = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            factorial_current = (a*factorial_next_num);
        }
        if(factorial_current % prime_number == 0) //determines if the prime number fits into current factorial number
        {
            current_number = (factorial_current/prime_number); //finds number of times prime number fits in
            total_number = (total_number + current_number); //adds total amount of times that prime has fit within the factorial
        } 
    }
    return total_number;
}

/* This function takes 2 integers as input (a factorial and a prime number) and then determines the next prime number within the limits of the factorial by finding the next prime number and testing it to see if it is a factor of the factorial */

int find_next_prime (int factorial, int current_prime) //function that determines the next prime within the factorial
{
    for(a=current_prime;a<factorial;a++) //checks all possible primes within the factorial
    {

        for(b=0;b<a;b++) 
        {       
            if (a % b == 0) //determines if the number is a prime number using remainder when divided by various numbers
            {
                return a; //returns the number if it is next prime
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

input.txt is below

```
5 
46 
89 
36 
0
```

Comment: You have two things **within** the outer loop supposedly controlled by `c` which interfere. First `a=scanf("%d", &c)` and also `for(c=0;c<5;c++)`. You also do not check the input value of `c` for its range.

Comment: Your file says "there are five test numbers" but contains only four.  Handling zero correctly may require special code; 0! is 1 by definition.  Note that `scanf()` can return 0 if there's an alphabetic character where a number is expected.  It is best to check `if (scanf("%d", &c) != 1) { …handle error… }`.

Comment: What range of factorials are you supporting?  You could easily create a table of prime factors for every number between 1 and a limit such as 100, and then use that in your calculations.  If you're planning to go larger, you have to be a little more careful, but there aren't all that many primes between 1 and 1000 (168 of them, to be precise).  So, any factorial up to 1000! isn't going to need more than 168 component primes.